# Python support Source Specific Multicast (SSM)

Tags: python, network-programming

I want to set up a multicast source specific communication between different application. One of them is a java application, another one a python application.

In java, i have started to develop with a `java.nio.channels.MulticastChannel`.

In python, i am looking for something equivalent but i can't figure if python provides support for *Source Specific Multicast (SSM IGMPv3)*.